# Finding matching point of two layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, intersect

I have two layers in ArcGIS:

- Highway layer (9000 data points (or values))
- Safe zone (4 types of values i.e. safe zone, medium zone, bad zone, and worst zone).

Now I want to do analysis to see how many highways data points fall into zones and how many do not fall in any zone.

I tried to use the Intersect tool to get the result but it didn't produce the desired result. It only gave those points that lie in a safe zone, it didn't return the points that do not lie in a safe zone.

What function should I use?

Comment: You could try a spatial join to add the attributes, but first what geometry types are your datasets? point/line/polygon? The options available are very different depending on what geometry type your safe zones and highways are.

Comment: @MichaelStimson highways are polyline  and zones are polygon.

Comment: What was the result of the intersect tool? You should end up with lines within the zones, attributed from both highways and zones, if not check that both datasets have spatial references set and that you haven't selected FID only in your intersect. A picture of your data and results would help conceptualize your operation, can you add one to your question.

Comment: Intersect tool gave me around 1100 points that lies in 4 four zones. However intersect does not return remaining points who do not lies in any zones. I was wondering is there any function that maps the highways points with zones and also returns those highway points who do not lies in any zone. P.S. I tried union function but apparently I couldnt connect highway layer with union function

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: @PolyGeo I edited the question

Comment: Use Union https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Union/00080000000s000000/ to join all the highways to all the zones and keep the highways outside the zones as well. Union is limited to 2 datasets in basic or standard licensing which should be enough. The output type will be line as the lowest dimension participating in the union (polygon = 2d, line = 1d and point = 0d). So when you say you can't connect highway to union what errors/behaviors are you experiencing?

Comment: When I tried to connect the highway layer with union function in model builder it does not show the "input features" option (this option comes up when I tried to connect with other layers).

Comment: The [Overlay analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/commonly-used-tools/overlay-analysis.htm) documentation has diagrams of inputs and output if you're unsure of which tool to use.  Intersect does not include polygons not present in both features, but Union does.

Comment: "A picture of your data and results would help conceptualize your operation, can you add one to your question", please?

Comment: I think Intersect is the right tool, but then you need to join the attributes that result back onto your original shapefile.

Comment: If Intersect tells you how many points are within a safe zone won't the number that are not be 9000 minus that number?